# How to set dateToday time in a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, date

I have a below code in my controller class.

```
String sMonth = String.valueof(dateToday.month());
String sDay = String.valueof(dateToday.day());
if(sMonth.length()==1){
    sMonth = '0' + sMonth;
}
if(sDay.length()==1){
    sDay = '0' + sDay;
}
```

Now, to cover the lines inside if condition my system date's month and day should be of single digit. So, i want to set the system dateToday as something (like 1/1/2012)which satisfy the condition for any day run of test class.

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: How did you set `dateToday`?

Comment: I did not set dateToday but would like to do that in test class.
So that when the above code is being executed in my controller , it gets the lines under if condition covered for any day the test class is run.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using `date.today()` or `system.today()` to get the date so you can do something like

```
if(test.isrunningTest())
{
 dateToday = date.newinstance(1960, 2, 2);
}
String sMonth = String.valueof(dateToday.month());
    String sDay = String.valueof(dateToday.day());
    if(sMonth.length()==1){
    sMonth = '0' + sMonth;
    }
    if(sDay.length()==1){
    sDay = '0' + sDay;
    }
```

It wiill cover your if condition.

There is one more approach make `dateToday` public variable or a private variable and access it using `@Testvisible` and set the value outside the method. When you call this method in test class just set the new value.

Comment: Then I will have to put this condition in my controller class right ? May I do something like this in my test class ?

Comment: @Rajeev I am afraid But you need to add this in main class. You can't do this in test class unless you make `dateToday` public variable and set the value. Also if you are updating `dateToday` in same method then this approach will not work.

Comment: Ok. :) 
Thank you. It anyway help me , just was curious to know if that is possible :) .

Comment: Noooo don't recommend `Test .isRunningTest()`. Kill it! Much better to use a `@TestVisible` variable that you *overwrite* when you need a different value.

Comment: @AdrianLarson if they set the value of `dateToday ` in same method then I don't think `@TestVisible` will help us.

Comment: So just move it to a top level variable if you need that level of control.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks. That I have already suggested him in comments.

Comment: Ah. But see, those are very easy to gloss over (Exhibit A), and you didn't add it to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a Utility class property

```
//  -----------------------------------------------
//  today       : getter/setter to have testemthod-driven different values for today
//  -----------------------------------------------
public static Date today        {get {return today == null ? Date.today() : today;} set;}
```

then, in your code, replace all uses of `Date.today()` with `Util.today`

Your test methods can then do

```
Util.today = Date.newInstance(1960,3,1);  // set test date
// invoke code under test (like the controller)
```

Comment: I would just use `@TestVisible static Date today = Date.today();` personally.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - for a localized case, sure -- but I like the system-wide solution that can coordinate multiple classes in a complex chain of method invocations

Comment: I guess so, but why the `get`/`set` here? Seems more kludgy than simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    String sMonth = String.valueof(dateToday.month());
// Make the value an Integer so you can test it's value
    Integer vSMonth = Integer.valueOf(sMonth);
// If it's greater than 0 but less then 10 get the right digit
    if(vSMonth > 0 && vSMonth) < 10) sMonth = sMonth.right(1);
```